# How to fill missing values using start and end values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have start and end value and there are n missing values. The logic to fill missing value is find average between start and end value.

psuedo-code is:

```
start_index = 0
end_index = len(l) 
while
    l[mid] = (l[start_index]+l[end_index])/2
    update start_index and end_index
    repeat
```

For ex, start = 10, end = 20 and missing values count is 4.

```
step - 1: l = [10, nan, nan, nan, nan, 20]

step - 2: l = [10. nan, 15, nan, nan, 20]  => (10+20)/2 = 15

step - 3: l = [10. 12.5, 15, nan, nan, 20] => (10+15)/2 = 12.5

step - 4: l = [10. 12.5, 15, 17.5, nan, 20] => (15+20)/2 = 17.5

step - 5: l = [10. 12.5, 15, 17.5, 18.75, 20] => (17.5+20)/2 = 18.75
```

How to do this in python or pandas.

I am unable to get optimised solution for this.
Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

What you want to do is simple linear interpolation between start and end values to fill the NA values. That is the definition of the `pd.DataFrame.interpolate` function. You can `limit_direction='both'`This will help with consecutive nans

Comment: A note: This is the best solution, although will give a different result - OP uses 2-point interpolation to only get a middle element &repeats, when "middle" is not always ideal. Thus it's a difference between [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20] (linear interpolation) and what OP has.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you meant but this solution works:

```
l = [10, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 20]
    
def get_end_index():
    for index, val in enumerate(l[start_index+1:]):
        if val is not np.nan:
            break
    return start_index + index + 1

while np.nan in l:
    start_index = l.index(np.nan) - 1
    end_index = get_end_index()
    mid_index = int((start_index + end_index)/2) 
    
    l[mid_index] =  (l[start_index]+l[end_index])/2
l
```